# looping through a list using raw input

Tags: python

I've been practicing python when i came across a dilemma. i can't figure out how to loop raw input through a list(using while) in order to generate a proper error message.

```
places_to_visit = {1 : 'London', 2 : 'Rome', 3: 'Amsterdam', 4: 'Paris'}
place = raw_input("where are you travelling to?:")
#gives the cost of travelling to a specific destination
while str(place) != ____:
    place = raw_input("Sorry i did not catch that. please enter your destination again:")

if str(place) == ____:
    def travel_cost(place):
        if place == "London":
            return 2000
        elif place == "Rome":
            return 3000
        elif place == "Amsterdam":
            return 3000
        elif place == "Paris":
            return 5000
```

any help will be much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: As an aside it is unnecessary to use `str(place)` as `raw_input` already returns a `str`, so it needs no conversion.

Comment: Please think about your indentation and the definition of the function `travel_costs`. Are you sure to define this function after getting an specific input string only?

Comment: i used str() as one of the many fruitless efforts to get a solution to my problem but thank you for reminding me.

Comment: and I'm working on the function now, be sure to work with your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

If you store your costs in a appropriate `dict` you can do the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

places_with_costs = {"London": 2000, "Rome": 3000, "Amsterdam": 3000, "Paris":5000}

while True:
    place = raw_input("Where are you travelling to?: ")

    if place in places_with_costs:
        print "Your trip is {}.".format(places_with_costs[place])
    else:
        print "Unable to find your destination. Try again."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `in` operator to see if an element is in a sequence

```
while place not in places_to_visit.values()
```

In this case you can test if their entered string is in the list of cities in your `dict`